# Assign stored procedure dynamic result to a table variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `SP_A` within a SQL CLR Assembly, `SP_A` returns a result set that is dyamic : when there's no error (caught and handled in C#) it returns fields `F1`, `F2` and `F3` and when there's a error it returns fields `F1`, `F2`, `F5` and `F6`.

I would like to create a stored procedure `SP_A_WRAP` that returns a resultset containing only `F1` and `F2`, here's what I did

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_A_WRAP ( @Param1 )
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RS TABLE (F1 NVARCHAR(MAX), F2 NVARCHAR(MAX), F3 NVARCHAR(MAX), F5 NVARCHAR(MAX), F6 NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @RS (F1,F2) EXEC dbo.SP_A @Param1
SELECT * FROM @RS
END
```

Executing SP_A_WRAP fails in both cases, the error is

> The name or column number of the values provided does not match the
>   table definition

Executing SP_A works fine in both cases.

Using `OPENROWSET` or `sp_executesql` is not an option

Modifying the CLR Assembly is not an option

Comment: The error is clear - the stored procedure returns *a different* number of columns. The number of columns must match the number of result fields. It's no different than writing `INSERT INTO @RS (F1,F2) SELECT 1,2,4,5`

Comment: Yeah this isn't going to work for you. Something has to change in order for you to do this. And maybe they are just names in your post but the sp_ prefix is not a great plan. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @SeanLange just names, I name stored procedures SP_... functions FN_... types TY.... and so on, apreaciate the tip though

Comment: Hopefully you didn't miss the point that SP_ is a bad idea. Honestly, I dislike prefixes as the do nothing but make it harder to work with. But that is a preference. :)